# How can I remove an iframe within an iframe on an external web page like Pinterest's bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, css

I am in the process of making a bookmarklet that allows users to highlight text on an external web page.

It runs JavaScript code that appends a JavaScript file from my server to the current web page that takes the title of the current web page, the URL of the current web page, and then the highlight text of the current web page.  Finally, the user would click a button to submit the data to my web server to be saved into the database.

I have two ways of doing this: (1) have a popup with the data in the URL as parameters, or (2) to have an iframe inserted into the current web page with a form to submit the data.

In the one with the popup (1), the users browser auto blocks the popup for every domain. How do I get around this?  It seems like Facebook share and twitter tweet buttons bypass the popup blocker though...

In the one with the iframe (2), I want to remove the iframe from the DOM after submitting data. However, if I'm on another domain, I get an error saying I am denied access because of origin policy something.  I know it's possible because Pinterest's bookmarklet does this, it inserts an iframe then removes it from the current DOM.

I am looking for information on how these solutions work, so I can do something similar with my bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a post message callback after saving the data from the iframe.